# Oracle create table error ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I don't know why i'm getting this error `(00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier")`. 
Could someone explain why this is happening?

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE regionclient(
    code_region NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    libelle VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Client(
    code_client NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    nom VARCHAR(30),
    adresse VARCHAR(100),
    date_contact DATE,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT fk_region 
        FOREIGN KEY (code_region) 
        REFERENCES regionclient(code_region)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the column to use it in a foreign key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Client (
    code_client NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    nom VARCHAR(30),
    adresse VARCHAR(100),
    date_contact DATE,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    code_region NUMBER(5),
    CONSTRAINT fk_region FOREIGN KEY (code_region) REFERENCES regionclient(code_region)
);
```

The constraint definition *references* a column.  It does not *define* the column.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7926b69c6d5794319e6c0fd65ca76819) is a db<>fiddle.